# How do I return a serialized response for field data not stored in ES

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
class Address {
    String address1, country, state, zip;
}

class Foo {
    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    Address work;

    boolean workAddressSameAsHome;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    Address home;
}
```

I would like to return work value as home in the JSON response if workAddressSameAsHome=true, as the value will not be stored in ES. How do I make this work for a GET request `/foo/<id>`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch does not offer any REST URLs, so I assume you are using Spring Data Rest on top.

BTW, your `Foo` class has no `@Document` and `@Id` property, I guess your real class has one.

What you can do in Spring Data Elasticsearch is to provide a bean that implements the `AfterConvertCallback` interface - available since Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0:

```java
@Component
public class SetWorkAddressAsHomeCallback implements AfterConvertCallback<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo onAfterConvert(Foo foo, Document document, IndexCoordinates indexCoordinates) {
        if (foo.workAddressSameAsHome) {
            foo.home = foo.work;
        }
        return foo;
    }
}
```

This callback is invoked after the document is read from Elasticsearch. Here I just copy the work address to the home address field.

For more information about the callbacks check the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.entity-callbacks

You might consider to implement a `BeforeConvertCallback` as well where you would clear the home address when the `workAddressSameAsHome` is true, this would be invoked before the entity is saved in Elasticsearch, thus preventing to store a home address in this case. But keep in mind that you won't be able to do an Elasticsearch search for the home address in this case.